# Appium Desktop cannot start an App installed via Microsoft InTune

Tags: appium, mobile-automation, android-automation

I'm using Appium Desktop 1.12.1. I want to start a new session and use Inspector.
I have a business app that is usually installed via **MS InTune**. 
Essentially InTune means I have two categories of app on my phone, 'Secure' and 'regular' - the secure software is downloaded through a corporate interface for Google Apps.

If I install the app from a download ie non-secure, Appium recognises it fine but if I install through secure Google Play, Appium does not find it - gives error 'Could not find package com.microsoft.d365.fs.mobile on the device'.
If I run the command '*dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus*' in ADB shell, I see result: 
 " *mCurrentFocus=Window{685d0fc u10 com.microsoft.d365.fs.mobile/md53e7154e02be292c1bcf686768e2066df.MobileCRMActivity}*". 
Ie the package 'com.microsoft.d365.fs.mobile' is exactly the same in the two install methods.

How do I get Appium to find the package installed via InTune? It is like I have a different partition on my phone. Note also that using something like 'Apk Info' app will not give any info for secure apps.
Cheers, Dan

Comment: I am also having the same issue.. Did you find any solution regarding to that app installed via Intune..

Comment: Hi - no luck yet. Having to install app manually on the phone so that it sits outside InTune